# How to filter based on multiple condition: ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

Im playing around with React and json data, i have an input field to search data from the json file.

I can figure out how to search one key of the json data, is there any chance of some help.

My code is:

```
if(searchString.length > 0){
    contactsData = contactsData.filter(function(l){
        return l.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
    });
}
```

where `l.name` i also want `l.company` and `l.email`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is concatenate all the three strings by using some character like `*`, `#` or any other, then check for `searchString`.

Like this:

```
if(searchString.length > 0){
    let str;
    contactsData = contactsData.filter(function(l){
        str = `${l.name}# ${l.company}# ${l.email}`;
        return str.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
    });
}
```

Or you can individually check also, like this:

```
return (
    l.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString ) || 
    l.company.toLowerCase().match( searchString ) || 
    l.email.toLowerCase().match( searchString )
);
```

Comment: Perfect, not sure why i didn't think of going down the option 2 route, for now i will go with that option as for me its a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**search on multiple condition**
in the given array you can search against firstName,lastName,email,phone.
if search query matched any of this values it will result of that.

{[{firstName:'Ali',lastName:'khan',email:'test@email.com',phone:12345}] .filter((a) =>
 `${a.firstName} ${a.lastName} ${a.email} ${a.phone}`.includes(
your search filed value here
)
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).